# sql group by days, but from certain hour

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select rows from table, grouped by days (I have my date written in unixtime in field `created_at`). So I am using `GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at))`. And it works fine. But I need to group my rows not from 00:00 to 23:59, I need it to group from 09:00 to 08:59. I tried `GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at) - 9/24)`, but with this some rows duplicates (I have 2 rows in table with same data). What do I do wrong?

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output.

Comment: Please go through this link once: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Here make use of having clause as ...group by your_date having to_char(your_date,'HH:MM') between '09:00' AND '08:59'

Answer (score 1):

You could use  a date_sub

```
GROUP BY date(DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at), INTERVAL 9 HOUR)
```